# Why is there no Console Window showing up whilst debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, console, gdb

Alright so I have been trying to fix this for a while, but with **NO SUCCESS**, I've come here to search for help instead. I'd appreciate it!

So basically, when I debug with gdb it should give me a console window saying "Hello World" (cause that is what I wrote in my code) right? Well you guessed, **there is no console window for me.**

This is the code i've written:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is supposed to give me an "Hello World" output in the console window but it is not, cause the console window is not even there when I debug. I've double checked almost everything and I can't find **ANY SOLUTION** at all.

*Thanks for listening as this is very frustrating for me.*

Comment: Add `char ch; cin >> ch;` after your `cout`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm or just `cin.get()`, no `char` needed

Comment: adding char ch; cin >> ch; after my cout made a difference but didn't work. There is still no Console Window showing up.

Comment: It's a while since I last used gdb, but if you don't have any GUI to it, there shouldn't be a second console. The "hello world" should just be printed inside the console you use for debugging.

Comment: @churill how do I add a GUI to it?

Sorry didn't have time to answer sooner

Comment: Do you call gdb via console or launch it via vs code (pressing f5 for example)? Maybe the answer below helps you or [this walkthrough](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_configure-debug-settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VSCode in `launch.json` file with a configuration of debug execution you can use

`"externalConsole": true`

which allows you to see your output not in the embedded terminal.

Comment: Thanks! This really worked. I can't believe I missed that option, thanks for the help!